# archive and visualize amazon ec2 cloudwatch metrics

Tags: amazon-ec2, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch

How do you backup your ec2 cloudwatch metrics? How do you visualize different measurements with different scales at once, like cpu% and i/o? How do you combine your application server metrics (like 'viewed products per hour') with cloudwatch metrics (cpu per hour)?

I thought about storing raw cloudwatch metrics in s3 first and then using munin for visualization. But maybe there is a more advanced approach which is more interactive than munin's static images.

Cheers,

Jan

Answer (score 0):

Zenoss can pull this data in and might be what your looking for. There's a video at http://community.zenoss.org/blogs/zenossblog/2011/01/06/free-monitoring-for-amazon-ec2-instances-with-zenoss